# TypeScript array inclusion check results in error

Tags: typescript

I have this array:

```
// I have this as a const since I need it as a type elsewhere
const fruits = ["strawberry", "banana", "orange", "grapefruit"] as const;
```

Then I try to check if an unknown value (from like a HTTP controller) is present in the array (to prevent lots of `x !== y` statements), like below:

```
const input: string = SomeRandomService.getMyString();

if(!fruits.includes(input)) {
  throw new Error("Not present");
}
```

That results in the following error message on the `.includes(input <-- this one)`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"strawberry" | "banana" | "orange" | "grapefruit"'.
```

Why does this occur? This seems like valid code to me, because I actually **want** to do that check to **prevent** it from **not being assignable** like TypeScript suggests me to do.

What is the solution to bypass this? (Except doing `input as any`)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your `fruits` to [`ReadonlyArray<string>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.2/lib/lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts#L30) which has `includes` by default but un-modifiable

```
// I have this as a const since I need it as a type elsewhere
const fruits = ["strawberry", "banana", "orange", "grapefruit"] as const;

const input: string = "testing";

if(!(fruits as ReadonlyArray<string>).includes(input)) {
  throw new Error("Not present");
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKagC5QJYGdQyzUBjAewDsNlQM1j8lJiEEATUNcnbFATwAckEAbDAgDuUBACcEAKCKlyAM3EBXVlgC8oANoAiMuJjCARhPGdtAGlDbDMYrZgWrhfcQDmCR9tf7eilcm0AXWwsWTIAbikZEjIWYm4lZAAuCmRxKldQDW1kBDIM7UipNHkACgBCUr9VENAAJQQYRhJ%20TgBBcX1OAB49DIA%20AEoAOip8fiVGPNKqBORBwdAAbylQFChxQmFQem2AUU7nUu0AOUJybkkhYgDByIBfIA)

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this, but you can wrap all the messy logic into a type-guarding function:

```
const fruits = ["strawberry", "banana", "orange", "grapefruit"] as const;

const isFruit = (value: string): value is typeof fruits[number] => {
  return fruits.includes(value as typeof fruits[number])
}

const input: string = "something";

if (!isFruit(input)) {
  throw new Error("Not present");
}
// now input is typed "strawberry"|"banana"|"orange"|"grapefruit"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EsoRgXhgbQETQICGA7gEYCmCCAnngDQx5lFitENMjFgDmFnPL2IAHColRQ8AXRhEMoSFADcAKEXQYKCADFkaLDAAUANyIAbJBQBcMQij4BKW2csUtGKDTEg48feg4YEgAtpQIspgAfDAA3qowMAgUUEgIYP6SEAB0DsCWACYUEKYWVnKe3hS+mWgQQaHh0o6qAL7q4JoOIkhQtvZ8hgQgISkAFg68eGoofkYAhNp6kkbdvY6OcQkwUGMIICQwYBSHAKLU3EZ4AHIgsCLJEBRgUo5q7RqwUMWw2Gsq20SAHogQA9AD8QA)